# My Java application can't connect to my side-by-side SQL Server 2005/2008 machine

Tags: java, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2005

I've got my dev machine running SQL Server 2005 and SQL Server 2008 side-by-side. I can connect just fine to my dev machine from the local SSMS and from SSMS on any other machine in our network. The server appears to be working fine in that sense.

My Java application can connect to any other SQL Server in our network (either 2005 or 2008 but not a side-by-side) but it cannot connect to MY side-by-side dev server. I am completely out of ideas.

Here is an example connection string that works

```
BlahDB.server=blah.env2.devqa.blah.net/BlahDB;instance=BlahDB4
BlahDB.user=BlahUser
BlahDB.password=blahuser
```

But when I change it to

```
BlahDB.server=mydevserver.env2.devqa.blah.net/BlahDB
BlahDB.user=BlahUser
BlahDB.password=blahuser
```

it does not work. I dropped the instance because I don't have one. It just does not connect despite the server working great when connection via SSMS.

My exception is not very helpful:

```
Caused by: java.sql.SQLException: Connections could not be acquired from the underlying database!
at com.mchange.v2.sql.SqlUtils.toSQLException(SqlUtils.java:106)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.C3P0PooledConnectionPool.checkoutPooledConnection(C3P0PooledConnectionPool.java:529)
at com.mchange.v2.c3p0.impl.AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.getConnection(AbstractPoolBackedDataSource.java:128)
```

Comment: What is SSMS? You do not define it

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio

Comment: OK, please insert that in your question, along with the scenario(s?) in which this studio can connect to the DB but your application cannot -- or whatever else the problem is. As it stands, your question is unclear.